# how do I get an equation to look like this? \begin{cases} doesnt seem to do exactly

Tags: equations, formatting

In a paper I'm reading, theres this equation which I'm trying to copy into my notes, but cant quite see how to format it like such?

[image]

I can do:

S_{i}^{(l_k)}=\left\{ [f_j^{(l_k)};v_{j}^{(l_k)}-p_i]^T  \right\}

but then how do I get the vline and the 3 conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\middle` and `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
S_{i}^{(l_k)}=
  \left\{ 
    [f_j^{(l_k)};v_{j}^{(l_k)}-p_i]^T
  \;\middle|\;
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    \lVert v_{j}^{(l_k)}-p_i\rVert < r_{k} \\[1ex]
    \forall v_{j}^{(l_k)}\in\mathcal{V}^{(l_k)} \\[1ex]
    \forall f_{j}^{(l_k)}\in\mathcal{F}^{(l_k)}
  \end{array}
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Quite likely the original used `\left[...\right]` and `\left\|...\right\|`, but the result is obviously wrong, because too big delimiters are chosen.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
S = \left\{ [stuff]^T \middle\vert \begin{array}{l} Cond.1 \\ Cond.2 \\ Cond.3 \end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]